# how to check if google places library place.photo array is empty

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I am using the google places api library and have come upon a problem, I am needing to see if the array is empty e.g if any photo exists

I have tried a few things, this being one of them.

```
var photoz = place.photos;

if (photoz[0] != null) {
alert('ok');
}
```

does anybody have any proposals to this problem.

Comment: what about `if(photoz.length)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(place.photos != undefined){
    alert('ok');
}
```

It means that there is a `photos` tag in it.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this.

```
if(place.photos){
   alert('photo tag exist');
}
```